# If someone has no hands or arms, how would they swear on a bible in court?

Tags: court

For example, if someone had some form of birth defect causing them to be born without arms.

Comment: With their feet.

Answer (score 1):

Even people *with* hands and arms don't have to touch a bible. This is explained in another answer here:

https://law.stackexchange.com/a/3924/3851